# grub-reboot xx is not working

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel, reboot

I have some dual-boot headless Pcs (win8.1 & 14.04/16.04) and sometimes I need to boot to windows. I have tried everything I can find and they are always totally ignored by grub at reboot.

This guy had the same problem 
[Grub: reboot to specific kernel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/838704/grub-reboot-to-specific-kernel)

I have tried all suggestions and still no selective reboot. It just goes back to the default which is Ubuntu, currently item #3 in the grub menu. Win8.1 is #2 in the menu. All # are zero-based of course.

This guy answers his own question and has a rather brute force approach.
[Reboot command is not working as expected in Ubuntu 14.04.3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/735370/reboot-command-is-not-working-as-expected-in-ubuntu-14-04-3)

Can someone please assist in making this work without having to roll back on all the PCs.

Thank you.